# What's the best way to update a folder using EWS?

Tags: email, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I've been working on syncing folders with the EWS API, and it's super useful that it returns `ChangeType` for creations/updates/deletions in `SyncFolderHierarchy`. However, in the `serviceObject`, all I get is the folder object that's been updated. Is there a good way of finding which folder has been changed, given that the `DisplayName` and `Id` are altered in the update?

The best that I have in mind is creating a new folder with the updated folder's properties and then reconciling my folder list with the folder list EWS has (i.e., finding that the old folder is no longer in the EWS folder list and deleting it), but I would be surprised if there weren't a better way of doing it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @MartindeRuiter Nope! 